# simulation of updating a dataset from real time data

Tags: python, datetime, random, pandas

In this code (reproducible example) I want to generate a dataframe composed by random dates in the first col, and by random numbers (in reality they will be generate from a socket) in the second column.

Another important feature I want to keep is that: since I need to update this date every *n-period* a "missmatch" can happen (network connection failure), I need to have the dataset without repetitions(previous data) in it.

I created three functions: `randomGen()`,`df_Gen()`for generate the dataframe, `entryPoint()` finds the *correct date* so that it will not include any repeated/previous data, avoiding this mistake.

Since I come from an R and C++ knowledge of coding, I still follow this type of coding.
So my feeling is that the code can be optimized a lot, but for now I don't know what to look for or optimize

Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import math
from random import gauss
import numpy as np


##CREATING DATETIME OBJECT
l = list()
num = list()
num = pd.DataFrame(num)

n = 10
df = []
data = []
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
date_temp = []
date_temp = pd.DataFrame(date_temp)

#iteration
i = 0
last_data = 0

dt_0 = datetime.datetime(year=2020,month=12,day=11,hour=12,minute=30,second=14)
#increment by 1 minute
dt_1 = dt_0+timedelta(hours=0,minutes=1,seconds=0)
dt_2 = dt_1.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")      ##trasform in string type(dt_1.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")) -> 'str'


def randomGen():
    global num
    my_mean = 10
    my_variance = 5
    random_numbers = [gauss(my_mean, math.sqrt(my_variance)) for x in range(n)]
    num = random_numbers
    num = pd.DataFrame(num)  ##pd Dataframe
    print("num:",num)
    print("")
    return num

def entryPoint():
    global last_date, idx_start, row2delete
    last_date = t1[0][0]

    for x in range(len(t0)):        #np.intersect1d(t0,t1)
        print("x:",x)
        if last_date==t0[0][x]:
            idx_start = x

    print(idx_start)



def df_Gen():
    global l,df,data,data_temp,i,dt_0,t0,t1

    for x in range(n):      #generating 1 minutes date
        dt_1 = dt_0 + timedelta(hours=0, minutes=x, seconds=0)
        dt_2 = dt_1.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        l.append(dt_2)

    if i==0:                                    #enter here once
        df = pd.DataFrame(l)
        data_temp = pd.concat([df, num], axis=1)     #cbind random num and dates
        data_temp = data_temp.T.reset_index(drop=True).T  ##reset column index
        data = data_temp
        t0 = df
        print("data:",data)
        print("")
        data_temp = []
        l = []

    if i>0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(l)
        data_temp = pd.concat([df, num], axis=1)     #cbind random num and dates
        data_temp = data_temp.T.reset_index(drop=True).T  ##reset column index
        t1 = df

        entryPoint()
        #data.drop(index=data.index[:3],axis=0) #delete first 3 rows
        data = data.head(idx_start)         ##keep first idx_start rows

        data = pd.concat([data,data_temp])
        data = data.reset_index()                           #reset rownames
        print("data:",data)
        print("")
        print("data_temp:",data_temp)
        print("")
        data_temp = []
        l = []

    #increasing by 5 minutes to create a missmatch between "data" and the next "data_temp"
    dt_0 = dt_0+timedelta(hours=0, minutes=5, seconds=0)
    print("i:",i)
    print("")
    print("")
    i = i + 1



####        RUN         ####
randomGen()
for j in range(2):
    df_Gen()
    print("data:",data)
```

How can I optimize this code? Is this a correct way of think an algorithm like this?
Any suggestion is welcomed.
Thanks